# How to match numbers followed by any combination of special characters and spaces using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am a newbie with regex and I am having trouble trying to match some parts of a string so I can remove it from a piece of entered text. I want to match digits followed by a sequence of a combination of any special characters + spaces. There could also be non Latin characters that should not be removed inside the sequence (for example Ñ).

for example inputted it may look like:

```
11@- &-.text
11 $ab*cÑ .somewords123
```

outputted I would expect

```
text
abcÑsomewrods123
```

I am using javascript replaceall method with regex to find it. So far I have something basic like this regex

```
.replaceAll(/\d+(\@|\s)+(\-|\$)+(\s|\&)+(\&)+(\-)+(\.)/g, '');
```

Is there a way to write this more efficiently so that it captures any special characters since the text can contain more different special chars than in the examples? Or is this a situation better handled with pure JS?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ether have blacklist of what you calling special characters, or whitelist of the allowed characters.

for blacklist it gonna look like:

```js
const blacklist = "!@#$%^&*()_+.";

const exampleInputs = [
    "te&*st+_1.",
    "te%%st^*2",
    "t@@@es*(*(*t3"
 ];
 
function removeSpecialChars(str) {
  const reg = new RegExp(`[${blacklist}]`, "g");
  return str.replace(reg, "");
}

exampleInputs.forEach(input => console.log(removeSpecialChars(input)));
```

for whitelist it gonna looks like:

```js
const whitelist = "0-9a-zA-Z";

const exampleInputs = [
    "te&*st+_1.",
    "te%%st^*2",
    "t@@@es*(*(*t3"
 ];
 
function removeSpecialChars(str) {
  const reg = new RegExp(`[^${whitelist}]`, "g");
  return str.replace(reg, "");
}

exampleInputs.forEach(input => console.log(removeSpecialChars(input)));
```